# spyder ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection '

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, spyder

```
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}

!cd Tensorflow && git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models
CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME = 'my_ssd_mobnet' 
!mkdir {'Tensorflow\workspace\models\\'+CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME}
!cp {PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH+'/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/pipeline.config'} {MODEL_PATH+'/'+CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMz4f.png)

i install tenserflow  and protobuf

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused because tensorflow-object-detection has not been installed.

Follow this [page](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tensorflow-object-detection-api-installation) to install